# Add rows in a table using reportlab django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, reportlab

I am using reporlab to generate pdf in my django project. I have multiple data which I want to store in a table format using reportlab. I create a table. But the table shows only first data no further data update in table rows.

The table looks like:

**Inspection_Id  |  Licence_Plate  |  Images  |  Comment**

**100 |   TEST |  http://www.test.com/image.jpg  |  Qwerty**

Code Snippet is Below:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from rest_framework import generics
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4, cm 
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet
from reportlab.platypus import Paragraph, Table, TableStyle
from reportlab.lib.enums import TA_JUSTIFY, TA_LEFT, TA_CENTER 
from reportlab.lib import colors

class DamageExportViewSet(generics.ListAPIView):

renderer_classes = [PDFRenderer,]

def get(self, request):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="Damage Report File.pdf"'
    width, height = A4
    styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
    styleN = styles["BodyText"]
    styleN.alignment = TA_LEFT
    styleBH = styles["Normal"]
    styleBH.alignment = TA_CENTER

    def coord(x, y, unit=1):
        x, y = x * unit, height - y * unit
        return x, y

    inspection = Paragraph('''<b>Inspection Id</b>''', styleBH)
    licplt = Paragraph('''<b>Licence Plate</b>''', styleBH)
    imgs = Paragraph('''<b>Images</b>''', styleBH)
    cmnts = Paragraph('''<b>Comments</b>''', styleBH)

    buffer = BytesIO()

    p = canvas.Canvas(buffer, pagesize=A4)

    p.drawString(20, 800, "Report generated at " + timezone.now().strftime('%b %d, %Y %H:%M:%S'))

    damage_data = Damage.objects.all()
    try:
        for i in damage_data:
            inspection_data = str(i.inspection_id).encode('utf-8')
            licence_plate = str(i.inspection.vehicle.licence_plate).encode('utf-8')
            images = str(i.image).encode('utf-8')
            comments = str(i.comment).encode('utf-8')
            inspcdata = Paragraph(inspection_data, styleN)
            lncplt = Paragraph(licence_plate, styleN)
            img = Paragraph(images, styleN)
            cmt = Paragraph(comments, styleN)
            data = [[inspection, licplt, imgs, cmnts],
                    [inspcdata, lncplt, img, cmt]]

    except:
        pass
    table = Table(data, colWidths=[4 * cm, 4 * cm, 5 * cm, 4 * cm])

    table.setStyle(TableStyle([
        ('INNERGRID', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.25, colors.black),
        ('BOX', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.25, colors.black),
    ]))
    table.wrapOn(p, width, height)
    table.wrapOn(p, width, height)
    table.drawOn(p, *coord(1.8, 9.6, cm))
    p.showPage()
    p.save()
    pdf = buffer.getvalue()
    buffer.close()
    response.write(pdf)
    return response
```

I don't understand how to show all data from **Damage** model in a table. And image data should be as the hyperlink.

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 2):

You are overwriting the `data` array at every loop step.
You need it to be something like this:

```
data=[
    ["Inspection_Id", "Licence_Plate", "Images", "Comment"],
    ["100", "TEST", "http://url.to/png", "Qwerty"],
    ["200", "2nd data row", "http://url.to/gif", "Dvorak"]
]
```

So that you can get something like

```
| Inspection_Id | Licence_Plate | Images            | Comment |
| ------------- |-------------- | ----------------- | ------- |
| 100           | TEST          | http://url.to/png | Qwerty  |
| 200           | 2nd data row  | http://url.to/gif | Dvorak  |
```

Therefore, your loop needs to look like:

```
# Fill the first row of `data` with the heading, only once!
data = [[inspection, licplt, imgs, cmnts]]
try:
    for i in damage_data:
        inspection_data = str(i.inspection_id).encode('utf-8')
        licence_plate = str(i.inspection.vehicle.licence_plate).encode('utf-8')
        images = str(i.image).encode('utf-8')
        comments = str(i.comment).encode('utf-8')
        inspcdata = Paragraph(inspection_data, styleN)
        lncplt = Paragraph(licence_plate, styleN)
        img = Paragraph(images, styleN)
        cmt = Paragraph(comments, styleN)

        # Add this loop's step row into data array
        data += [inspcdata, lncplt, img, cmt]
```

And that should be it :)

> And image data should be as the hyperlink.

What do you mean with this?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

If your main goal is to iterate and show the damage_data records in a table, then try the following:

```
(...)

damage_data = Damage.objects.all()
data = []
data.append(["Inspection_Id", "License_Plate", "Images", "Comment"])
try:
    for i in damage_data:
        row = []
        inspection_data = str(i.inspection_id).encode('utf-8')
        licence_plate = str(i.inspection.vehicle.licence_plate).encode('utf-8')
        images = str(i.image).encode('utf-8')
        comments = str(i.comment).encode('utf-8')
        row.append(inspection_data)
        row.append(license_plate)
        row.append(images)
        row.append(comments)
        data.append(row)
(...)
```

This should iterate through your damage_data queryset and populate your table.